How to Send Files from LWC to SFTP Server Using FTP-API in Salesforce
I'm creating an LWC that takes a file and sends it to an FTP folder. I'm using FTP-API for the middleware. You'll find the LWC and controller below. When I try to upload the file, I get this error

the JS function
handleUploadFinished(event) { 
        const file = event.target.files[0]; 
        this.file = file; 
        console.log('File: ' + JSON.stringify(file)); 
        const documentId = file.documentId; 
        const fileName = file.name;
        uploadFileToFtp({ documentId: documentId, fileName: fileName}) 
        .then(response => { 
            this.dispatchEvent( 
                new ShowToastEvent({ 
                    title: 'Success', 
                    message: 'File uploaded successfully!'+response, 
                    variant: 'success' 
                }) 
            ); 
        }) .catch(error => { 
            this.dispatchEvent( 
                new ShowToastEvent({ 
                    title: 'Error', 
                    message: error.body.message, 
                    variant: 'error' 
                }) 
            ); 
        }); 
    }

the html
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Upload File" icon-name="custom:custom63">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <!-- Lightning File Upload for file selection -->
            <lightning-file-upload
                label="Select a file to upload"
                name="fileUploader"
                accept=".pdf,.txt"
                record-id={recordId}
                onuploadfinished={handleUpload}>
            </lightning-file-upload>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>

and the controller
@AuraEnabled
    public static Integer uploadFileToSftp(Map<String, String> file) {
        try {
            // Create the HTTP request
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setEndpoint('https://www.ftp-api.com/ftp/upload'); 
            req.setMethod('POST');
            req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            
            // Set headers as required by FTP-API.com
            req.setHeader('username', 'myusername');
            req.setHeader('password', 'mypassword'); 
            req.setHeader('port', '21');            
            req.setHeader('ftp-host', 'myhost'); 
            req.setHeader('ftp-type', 'SFTP');       
            
            
            String body = JSON.serialize(new List<Map<String, String>>{file}); 
            req.setBody(body); Http http = new Http(); 
            HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
    
            System.debug('Request sent');
    
            return res.getStatusCode();
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Log the exception
            System.debug('Exception: ' + e);
            throw e;
        }
    } 


Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  What is your question or issue?  Please [edit] your post to describe the problem.

Thanks David, my bad for forgetting the question
